# Copy a row in a CSV file based on a value in another column

Tags: csv, clipboard, read

I have a file of 800+ rows.  Each row has a certain number of individuals we have to measure a trait on (n = 3, 5 or 10).
I would like to expand the file so each individual has their own row based on the number we needed to measure (n).
For example:

```
Row     Who/What        Description     n
8001    Maize line      Control         3
```

Would become:

```
Row     Who/What        Description     n
8001    Maize line      Control         3
8001    Maize line      Control         3
8001    Maize line      Control         3
```

I am not proficient in Unix (still learning!), but I get that I'd need to read in the txt/csv file, then copy based on the n in the fourth column.  I would not need to repeat the column headers, that was just for organization.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is it really a CSV (comma separated) file? if not, what is the actual column delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

try with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print; next } { repeat=$NF; while (repeat--) print } ' infile
```

your given sample file is not a .csv file which supposed to be comma separated; you will need to specify what delimiter is used in your input file with awk's `-F` option.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{ print; next } { repeat=$NF; while (repeat--) print } ' infile
```

---

answer to the question asked in the comment:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print; next } { bakup=$1; repeat=$NF; 
            while (repeat--) { $1=bakup"."++dup; print }; dup=0 }' infile
```

Comment: You're right, I was trying to be clear in my example so I pasted the tabulated version.  Here is my csv:
`Row,Who/What,Description,Phenotype n`
`8001,B73xM21_BC1S4,LANMLR45B010,3`
Would it be possible append the the repeat number to the first column?  8001 becomes 8001.1, 8001.2, 8001.3, etc?
I really appreciate the 'awk' code!  I really need to work on my awk'ing, it's so powerful!

Comment: Worth revising the original question to reflect this new request.

Comment: @MichaelSyring just updated in answer